# c# realtime network text editor

Tags: c#, wpf, networking, text-editor

So... it's rather complicated, but basically I want to make a network based text editor, where multiple people can edit the same document at the same time. Think Google Docs. How would I go about doing this?

If it helps any, I have an FTP server, and a MySql database.

Comment: In order to make it you also need a visual studio and magic coding ball.

Comment: So you're saying it can't be done?

Comment: It can be done, but SO is not the site which will help you. Until you get more specific questions.

Comment: On keypress event, via AJAX call send the value of the text input to the server.  Save to the database or some server variable.  Then using similar method, poll for updated value from server every n seconds and update the text input with the latest value.  If this answer doesn't suffice... oh well.. garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: I see no question marks in the body of your text.

Comment: Updated with a question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to *create* one, or do you need one? If the latter then try [EtherPad](http://ietherpad.com/), it's great for that.

If you want to create it, well, the [source](http://code.google.com/p/etherpad/) to EtherPad is available, you could use it as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking only about text-editing i.e. no formatting, then it can be done fairly easily. Operational transformation is the way to go (it also supportformatting but the text-only-editing part is a lot easier to work out and implement). Etherpad uses it to power it's collaboration capability. There are plenty of algorithms out there. You can start off by taking a look at this http://cooffice.ntu.edu.sg/otfaq/.